# High voltage pad buffer design with 2nF load and ringing on first stage output

Tags: high-voltage, buffer, load, sine, capacitive

I am trying to design a high voltage (12V) buffer that will drive a sine wave with rail-to-rail peak-to-peak amplitude and a big capacitive load, maybe 3nF.
Browsing I came upon this Master's project: [High Speed Digital CMOS Input Buffer Design by Krishna Duvvada](https://cmosedu.com/jbaker/students/theses/High%20Speed%20Digital%20CMOS%20Input%20Buffer%20Design.pdf)

On page 14 (PDF page 30) there is a very basic rail-to-rail differential input, one with NMOS and other with PMOS for input pair, apparently self-biased, going over to two push-pull amplifiers buffering the output.

[image: Figure 2.23 Schematic diagram of a rail to rail input buffer from Master's project "High Speed Digital CMOS Input Buffer Design" by Krishna Duvvada]

(This circuit is credited in the project paper footnote {1} to the book:
R. Jacob Baker, *CMOS Circuit Design, Layout and Simulation, 2nd ed.* Boise, ID:Wiley-IEEE, 2005.)

I tried setting this up in Cadence, with reference voltage connected to the inverting input, as described in the pdf.
The only thing I left out was the switch MOSFETs, the NMOS M7 after the first stage and the M6PT and M5B because I wanted to see the effect described and because for first time testing I didn't deem it necessary. Although, I have a question about those switches too.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzE9tD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I just drew the schematic for easier referencing. I never used this tool though. I ended with two inverter symbols...
When I tested with reference voltage tied to inverting input, the results were ok.
When I configured it as a buffer, with the inverting input connected to the output (`out2` on my Circuit lab picture) I see a lot of ringing.

[image: Results of sin way into a buffer with ringing]

I seem to lack knowledge about this, so I would appreciate pointers too.
Here are my questions:

1. Why is there ringing? Where does it come from? You can see ringing at `out1` which looks terrible and then there's little bit of ringing left on the `out2` (I didn't expect it to change so much at `out2`, I would appreciate a comment there too).
2. How can I get rid of it?
3. The self-biased part of this circuit, I am not sure if this is a good way to do it. Doesn't it seem like, if done this way, the biasing transistors are always changing stable states? From what I see, they don't reach saturation, they stay in linear state. Judging by results, it seems kind of ok, the voltages seem high enough to have enough current, but I have a feeling there may be a better approach?
4. It is supposed to be a buffer on a pad where size and consumption matter and with a big 3nF capacitive load, I would appreciate any ideas what to look into.

Answer (score 0):

For a rail-to-rail output stage: I suggest looking at the Monticelli output stage, which was published back in the late 80's:
Author:  D.M. Monticelli.
Title:  "A quad CMOS single-supply op amp with rail-to-rail output swing".
Publication:  IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits, Volume: 21, Issue: 6, Dec 1986.

This output stage was examined in detail by Horowitz & Hill in their book "The Art of Electronics: The X Chapters", which you may be able to find at this link:-

https://x.artofelectronics.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/4xp11_RR_op-amps.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will look into it